# Write Hebrew Characters on Console Window, C#

Tags: c#, unicode, console, readline, hebrew

How can the user be able to write Hebrew Characters in console window which appears now to show question marks, This is what I Have:

```
        Encoding hebrewEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
        Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
        Console.WriteLine("Write your input:");
        string Input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you set the registry like explained here : 
[איך אפשר לראות עברית ב](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/technet/2013/06/11/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9A-%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%91-powershell-console/)

run -> regedit --rightclick choose new string.

After that 
Try this instead :

```
     Console.OutputEncoding = new UTF8Encoding();
     Console.InputEncoding = new UTF8Encoding();
       Console.WriteLine("Write your input:");
            string Input = Console.ReadLine();
```

If you want output only :

```
//It will display hebrew letter to console 
  Console.OutputEncoding = new UTF8Encoding();
       Console.WriteLine("\u05D0\u05D1");
        Console.WriteLine("אריאל");
        Console.WriteLine(new string("אריאל".Reverse().ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply changed InputEncoding to OutputEncoding:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
```